# Android widget fails to start activity when clicked first time

Tags: android, android-widget, android-pendingintent

I have an android widget which is actually a button to start an activity.The widget works fine using this code but there is a small bug :

When I add the widget to the home screen , clicking it first time doesn't do anything , second time it works. Then it works normally from 1st click. And the same thing happens when the phone is restarted.Can someone help me solve this problem ??

**MyWidgetIntentReceiver.java**

```
public class MyWidgetIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals("Start")) {
        onUpdate(context);
    }
}


private void onUpdate(Context context) {
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.widget_demo);

    Intent configIntent = new Intent(context, WidgetFlash.class);
    configIntent.putExtra("widget", 1);
    configIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    PendingIntent configPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
            0, configIntent, 0);

    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_button,
            configPendingIntent);

    MyWidgetProvider.pushWidgetUpdate(context.getApplicationContext(),
            remoteViews);
} }
```

**MyWidgetProvider.java :**

```
    public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_demo);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_button, buildButtonPendingIntent(context));

    pushWidgetUpdate(context, remoteViews);
}

public static PendingIntent buildButtonPendingIntent(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("Start");
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}

public static void pushWidgetUpdate(Context context, RemoteViews remoteViews) {
    ComponentName myWidget = new ComponentName(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
    AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    manager.updateAppWidget(myWidget, remoteViews);     
}}
```

**Widget in Manifest:**

```
   <receiver android:name="com.hybernect.flashlight.MyWidgetProvider" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/demo_widget_provider" />
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.hybernect.flashlight.MyWidgetIntentReceiver"
        android:label="widgetBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="Start" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/demo_widget_provider" />
    </receiver>
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work the first time, you should look at the logcat when you click it the first time. You may see something in there that is useful/informative.

Comment: logcat shows nothing on first click :(

Comment: Are you filtering the logcat? If so, please don't. You'll miss something important.

Comment: Please post your manifest

Comment: Do you have a configuration activity defined for your widget?

Comment: Please check the code , I updated the question

Comment: Add debug logging to your `onUpdate()` and `onReceive()` methods to see when these methods are called.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you might be very new to Android widgets, and are missing some of the basics that you need to know. My advice is to find some more tutorials other than the one you worked off, to compare different ways that widgets are handled.

I wrote a simple widget as a demo tutorial - it contains all the boilerplate code required for a widget, and very little else:

- [WiFi Widget Demo (github)](https://github.com/mobiRic/WifiWidget)
- [WiFi Widget (Play store)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobiric.demo.wifiwidget)

I wrote it in such a way to make it easy for anyone to remove the "wifi" related code, and adapt it to their own widget requirements. It might be perfect for you to look at, and relatively simple to add a single button to it.

---

You are mixing up the different `onUpdate()` methods in your `MyWidgetIntentReceiver` and `MyWidgetProvider`. Below I will try to explain what is wrong with the code that you gave in your original question.

---

When you add the widget to the home screen, `MyWidgetProvider.onUpdate()` is called, which in turn calls `buildPendingIntent()`:

```
public static PendingIntent buildButtonPendingIntent(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("Start");
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

This creates a `PendingIntent` that will send a broadcast with action set to "Start", when the button is clicked.

And that is what happens. The button is clicked, you send a broadcast with "Start" in it, and this is received by your `MyWidgetIntentReceiver`.

*I do not understand why you have chosen to do it this way, as you could rather just start the activity from this class.*

---

When your `MyWidgetIntentReceiver.onReceive()` method runs, it calls its own `onUpdate()` method.

(Note: this is poor practice; try to do as little as possible within a `BroadcastReceiver`)

This new `onUpdate()` method sets the click action to launch the activity:

```
Intent configIntent = new Intent(context, WidgetFlash.class);
configIntent.putExtra("widget", 1);
configIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

PendingIntent configPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
        0, configIntent, 0);

remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_button,
        configPendingIntent);
```

And so the second time you click the button, the `WidgetFlash` activity is launched.

---

To summarise:

- your first update calls `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`, which sends "Start" to the receiver
- your second update calls `PendingIntent.getActivity()`, which starts the `WidgetFlash`

I do not understand the need for your `MyWidgetIntentReceiver` in this code.

Comment: Now it is not working at all ? I changed the onUpdate in MyWidgetIntentReceiver to the new method you poster  and the button now doesn't do anything

Comment: I did not post any new method. This is all your original code. Tell me, why did you decide to use a `MyWidgetIntentReceiver`? It looks like you have the basics all wrong.